# NavigationLink init(_:destination:) deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

`NavigationLink`'s initializer

```
init<S>(_ title: S, destination: Destination) where S : StringProtocol
```

is deprecated and only available for iOS 13.0–15.2. The replacement is

```
init<S>(_ title: S, destination: () -> Destination) where S : StringProtocol
```

per the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:destination:)-6hslu.

Replacing my existing code with

```
NavigationLink("MyTitle") {
    Text("MyView")
}
```

shows the error

```
Type '() -> Text' cannot conform to 'View'
```

[image: NavigationLink initializer error]

What's wrong with my use of the recommended initializer?

EDIT 1:
Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

Comment: That code is compiling fine for me. Clear DerivedData? Restart Xcode?

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure this happens in a clean environment (ie try pasting it into a blank Xcode project)? Perhaps it's getting affected by some sort of surrounding code.

Comment: Yep, that's how I tested it. What's weird is that the SwiftUI source for NavigationLink only shows initializers for `destination: Destination` and none of the `destination: () -> Destination` initializers. Could I somehow have a stale version of SwiftUI? Though I don't know how that would be possible since all of these initializers are from iOS 13.

Comment: Cross-posting to apple developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696861

Comment: Compiled fine with Xcode 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from Xcode 12.5.1 (12E507) to 13.2.1 (13C100) fixed this.

The SwiftUI source in Xcode 12 did not contain the NavigationLink initializers with the destination parameter as a closure type; Xcode 13 did.